# How to retrieve all the Data Extension having similar name?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I want to retrieve all the DataExtension having similar kind of name.
For example if I have 4 DE having name

1. Mannya_grocery_de
2. Manav_goods_de
3. Manjeet_de
4. Amarjeet_de

So Now If I am passing "man" in DEval it should return all the DE that has "man" or "Man" in their name.
But by using below code it return me the "Mannya_grocery_de" only.

```
var FindDE = DataExtension.Retrieve({
Property:DEprop,SimpleOperator:"like",Value:DEval}
                                 );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop though the results and store it in an array and display it.

```js
<script runat='server' language='javascript'>
Platform.Load('Core','1.1'); 

var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    try {
    
            var req = api.retrieve("DataExtension", ["Name"], {
                Property: "Name",
                SimpleOperator: "like",
                Value: "Man" /* Update your DE name here*/
            });

            var arr = [];

            var results = req.Results;

            for (var k in results) {
                var nm = results[k].Name;
                if (nm.indexOf("_") != 0) arr.push(nm);
            }

        var result = arr.join(", ");
        Write(Stringify(result));
        
    } catch(error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }   
</script>
```

You can find more details [here](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-use-wsproxy-to-work-with-data-extensions-in-ssjs/#get-all-de-names)

> Thanks to [Ivan Razine](https://ampscript.xyz/about/)